# Best practice to check permission

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm in doubt about where permissions should be done.. Example, I have a PersonController which has two methods, a HttpGet create and a HttpPost create and I'm using a service layer which communicates with repository layer.
Now, what is the best way?

1:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        new PersonService().Save(person, (int)Session["UserId"]);//I check here permission here

        return RedirectToAction("Home","Home");
    }

    return View();
}
```

2:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var personService = new PersonService();

            if(personService.UserHasPermission((int)Session["UserId"]){
                 personService.Save(id);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Home","Home");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

in other words, should I do it inside business layer or in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether you're talking about permission to access resources or permission to perform operations in your domain.

You should use the [[Authorize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute to control access of **resources**. E.g:

> The URL **/admin/index** should only be available to Admins.

You should use your domain to enforce business logic on particular operations. E.g:

> User A can only perform operation B if condition C is met.

You should mix both practices depending on the scenario.

Comment: Ok, but if I need a permission to see a content? Should I check the permission inside 'PersonService.GetById()'? I dont like this very much.

Comment: @murilokunze - what does "to see a content" mean? If your talking about viewing a particular page, then it should be the `[Authorize]` attribute. If your talknig about *portions* of content on a page, then it should be done in the controller/view model setup, or via a more specialized domain query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a business detail that should be implemented regardless of the "UI" technology, so I would recommend checking access permission on the business layer and not the controller.

This will allow you to stay DRY by not having to reimplement this if you were to create something like a web service or any other UI that would need to call PersonService.Save(id)

Comment: Ok, but if I need a permission to see a content? Should I check the permission inside 'PersonService.GetById()'? I dont like this very much.